# How to display error message in Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I load data to my Highcharts dynamically via ajax calls. While ajax call is in progress, I display spinner for user with ".showLoading" function and when it is finished I hide spinner and show data.
And now I'm trying to implement error handling for ajax calls. If request failed I want to hide spinner and display error message.

```
my_chart = Highcharts.chart(...)  // create my desired chart with no data

my_chart.showLoading('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-3x fa-fw"></i>'); // show spinner while loading

$.getJSON('/chart_JSON', function(data){ // load data via ajax
    my_chart.addSeries(...) // add data to chart
    my_chart.hideLoading(); // hide spinner
})
.fail(function() {
    my_chart.hideLoading(); // hide spinner
    // display error message in place of chart ???
})
```

There is "no-data-to-display.js" plugin for Highcharts (http://code.highcharts.com/modules/no-data-to-display.js). It displays responsive message in the center of every chart if there is no data in it. And you can customize it with

```
Highcharts.setOptions({lang: {noData: "my message"}})
```

But:

- message also displays while data for chart is loading (under my spinner)
- message is the same for all charts

I want my error message to be something like "Server error, try to reload page", but I don't want to display it while chart is loading. How can I do it in a most responsive and natural way?

Comment: Check this fiddle, May be help you..[http://jsfiddle.net/6o8o03fe/1/]

Comment: In [highchart's example](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/no-data-to-display/no-data-line) they use `chart.hideNoData()`. This hides the noData message, so you could do that somewhere in your script. Then in the fail function call:`chart.showNoData("Your custom error message");`

Comment: @ewolden - thanks! That is exactly what I need!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with mentioned "no-data-to-display.js" plugin and its ".hideNoData()", ".showNoData()" functions.

```
my_chart = Highcharts.chart(...)  // create my desired chart with no data

my_chart.hideNoData();
my_chart.showLoading('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-3x fa-fw"></i>'); // show spinner while loading

$.getJSON('/chart_JSON', function(data){ // load data via ajax
    my_chart.addSeries(...) // add data to chart
    my_chart.hideLoading(); // hide spinner
})
.fail(function() {
    my_chart.hideLoading(); // hide spinner
    my_chart.showNoData("Server error, please reload page");
})
```

Thanks to @ewolden for this answer.

Comment: `showNoData` is not a function of `chart`